# Make [responsiveness] and [responsive-design] synonyms of [responsive]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I was browsing through the questions on the front page this morning and the first thing I saw was a question tagged [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive), [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) and [responsiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsiveness).

A few of the next questions were tagged with synonyms of [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive), and I think we should remove all synonyms of [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive) (but keep [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive) as it's the most broad) to keep things concise

Comment: For additional context: the oldest tag is "responsive design" with a tag wiki. "Responsiveness" seems to refer to a different term (not about layout, but about time). "Responsive" is the newest tag and tries to be different from the "responsive design", though it's unclear (at least for me) what the distinction is.

Comment: There is no distinction, except that presumably [responsive] isn't limited to "design" like [responsive-design]. Personally, I think it's a meaningless tag that attempts to lump every web technology and API regarding modern web development into one umbrella so that people don't need to find more specific tags like [media-query] and the like.

Comment: https://twitter.com/NOVALISTIC/status/1189420857766006785